# How to get xml attribute and values using JAXB

Tags: xml, parsing, jaxb

I am new in Jaxb i have one xml file which contain many attribute so i want the attribute with value

My XMl

```
     <message_mapping>    
<message Rtype="DIAGNOSTIC" direction="2" name="Diagnostic" mode="">
            <field tag="USERNAME"       source="I" tranData="username"  required="false" dataType="string" defaultValue="" />
            <field tag="PASSWORD"       source="I" tranData="password"  required="true"  dataType="string" defaultValue="" />
            <field tag="LOCALDATETIME"  source="E" tranData="trxDateTime" required="true"     dataType="string" defaultValue=""/>
</message>
</message_mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have your class 
MessageMapping.java which has in turn a list (or one? dunno) of message of type Message.java.
Message.java in turn will be structured with a list of Field of type Field.java.
The classes will be as follow:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Field {

        @XmlAttribute
        private String tag;

        @XmlAtrribute
        private String source;

        @XmlAtrribute
        private String tranData;

        @XmlAtrribute
        private String dataType;

        @XmlAtrribute
        private String defaultValue;

        /*
        GETTER AND SETTER HERE
        */

    }
```

And Message.java like this:

```
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class Message {
            private List<Field> fields;
            private String Rtype;
            private String direction;
            private String name;
            private String mode;

            /*
            GETTER AND SETTER HERE
            */
        }
```

And ultimately message_mapping class will need to be built as you see fit to accomodate a list of message or a single one, dunno what are your specification.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but any example of ultimately message_mapping class  you have ?

Comment: @XmlRootElement
public class MessageMapping {
List<Message> messages;
/*
YOUR GETTER AND SETTER HERE
*/
}

But you do know that if you have a xsd you can just build the classes automatically via jaxb, correct?

Comment: thankyou  i try but in field class without getter setter they read correct